# Multi Self-hosted Azure pipeline agents on same server

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We currently have more than one self-hosted Azure pipeline agents running on one server. Recently we have notices the pipelines are failing with "Network Path Issues", looks like all the steps run on one agent and somehow one of the steps jumps to a different agent causing it to fail. Is there a way to separate this other than creating new servers for each agent?

Comment: Instead of creating new servers, maybe you can consider adding new agent pool in web portal,separate the agents in different agent pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through lot of logs and all the pipelines that were having issues was able to find some similarities. Most of the issues were having on the step where we were using Powershell task and the task was outdated (replaced with new one by Azure). After updating all the powershell tasks the issue seems to have gone.

Answer (score 0):

> Looks like all the steps run on one agent and somehow one of the steps
>   jumps to a different agent causing it to fail. Is there a way to
>   separate this other than creating new servers for each agent?

I can't reproduce same issue on my side. I assume the self-agents you mentioned above are in same agent pool, if so, as I know Devops doesn't have one option to separate agents from same agent pool when these agents are installed in same machine.

About the strange behavior you met, you can try this to resolve it:

1.Since you may have more than one self-agents in **same** Agent Pool running in **same** server, I suggest you can try separate those agents in different Agent Pool. Since your agents are running in same server, in this situation one agent pool for one agent can be more suitable.

2.Assuming your steps may not in same agent job, check and make sure your different agent jobs use same agent pool.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: How will putting them on a different pool make any difference? Is this issue not because they are trying to use same resources? Thanks

Comment: I'm bit confused about `looks like all the steps run on one agent and somehow one of the steps jumps to a different agent causing it to fail`, it looks like more than one agent runs your steps in build pipeline, so I suggest you put those agents in different agent pool because different agents may have different configurations when installing agents. Could you share some more details about the strange network-path behavior so that I can understand your issue better.

Comment: And if only one agent is called to run your build pipeline, I don't think the cause of issue could be that they're trying to use same resources...